# Unity 5 doesn't see my PS4 controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gamepad

I've been seeing people use XBOX, PS3 and PS4 controllers for awhile now but haven't had a reason to mess with them until now. Today I purchased a PS4 Dual Shock 4 wireless controller. I'm running Unity 5 on a MacBook Pro with latest OS X version. OS X and several other apps I have installed can "see" and use the controller but Unity doesn't register it's existence.

I've tried turning the controller on before starting unity and after starting unity. I've tried building my test project as a stand alone app. I've tried various free input managers from the asset store but I still have no joy. I've also done the above mentioned things with the controller via bluetooth and via a usb cable. In all cases OS X and my other apps saw the controller but unity did not.

Am I missing something? I expected issues from the XBOX controller but it seems like everyone else I've been reading about has no issues with the PS3 and PS4 controllers. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

**Update**: I've confirmed this has something to do with Unity 5. I had a Mac Mini with Unity 4.6 on it and everything worked fine. I then installed Unity 5 and the controller is no longer seen.

**Update**: Dan W with Unity Support responded back on another thread.  I'll redirect to it for the sake of getting everyone in the same place.

And just for further info, the same is true for xbox controllers.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/952048/how-to-get-unity-to-see-my-ps4-controller.html

Comment: Tried to connect it via usb cable?

Comment: yes.  In Unity 4.6 everything works fine either way but when I open up a project in Unity 5 it no longer can see the controller

Comment: I just connected DS4 and Unity detected it. I also installed Virtual Bus Driver that comes with this tool - http://ds4windows.com/ . Maybe it could help.

Comment: I'm running on a Mac.  I don't have a windows box to test the connection on at the moment.  Do you have a  Mac you could try this on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know the Unity team has confirmed this is an issue but if you are looking for a work around Rewired has worked for me in the mean time.  I'd like to say that the team will have this fixed shortly but we all know they have a lot on their plate so using a 3rd party asset seems to be the quickest solutions right now.

As a side note, I'm not affiliated with Rewired and don't get anything for recommending them.  The author just contacted me using Unity Forums and suggested I try his demo.  I did and it works.  Do other input managers work?  Probably.  I however am happy with what I've seen so far from Rewired and I know it worked in my case so that's why I'm suggesting it.